# Filtering of imported date from sharepoint in qliksense

Tags: date, sharepoint, expression, qliksense

Data imported from sharepoint to qliksense is in the format "2020-08-30T18:30:00Z". And I want to filter out the columns based on the month(2020-Aug). I have converted the date format "2020-08-30T18:30:00Z" to "31/08/2020" using the expression:

```
Date(ConvertToLocalTime([REPORTED_x0020_DATE],'New Delhi'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

In filterpane, given expression is :

```
[REPORTED_x0020_DATE.autoCalendar.YearMonth]
```

The problem  is that after conversion the dates are just previous to the dates in sharepoint. So that, result getting after filtering is not right.

The mismatch of dates are shown in the image attached. Because of this mismatch not getting actual results on filtering.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that although you see just dates due to the format string, the underlying data still have timestamps returned from `ConvertToLocalTime`.

Try to truncate the timestamp by using floor:

```
Date(Floor(ConvertToLocalTime([REPORTED_x0020_DATE],'New Delhi')),'DD/MM/YYYY')
```

Comment: The problem is that after conversion the dates are just previous to the dates in sharepoint. So that, result getting after filtering is not right. How can I resolve this.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Could you please go through the image I shared along with the question.

Comment: New Delhi is many hours ahead of UTC, which your `[REPORTED_x0020_DATE]` should  be, else you should not be using `convertToLocalTime`

Comment: my issue is not with 'convertToLocalTime'. Actual time entered in sharepoint is the one entered in 'convertToLocalTime' column, not in '[REPORTED_x0020_DATE]'. So when am using '[REPORTED_x0020_DATE]' for  filtering the data the problem occurs.

Comment: Well then, you'll have to add the converted values as a dimension in your model and use that instead. Or, create a calculated dimension.